# How can I prevent email spam (too many instant emails on actions)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now any time someone comments on a post the poster gets an email.

What I would instead like to do is send an email the next day saying "There were 14 people who commented on this today. Check it out: link"

What would be the strategy to create this type of notification and bundle it up so only one email is sent instead of 14? How do you queue it up for the next day? Is it best to use cron for this? Some type of worker for delayed job or I'm not really sure at all how to architect this off of Heroku so please let me know. I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having a cron job that runs a rake task that does this. Have an attribute on each comment that indicates whether it is a 'new' comment or not, and each day when the cron goes through the comments mark them as 'not new' (or something that makes sense to you). write your query so that it only returns the 'new' comments, and doesn't loop through every comment in the db and then check to see if it is 'new' or not.

check out the [whenever gem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjavan%2Fwhenever&ei=AhUDUqG6L6OCyAHr0YD4Aw&usg=AFQjCNEn5ePCqSDQd0VvjryJOOz1_qziPw&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aWc). I haven't used it, but there are [plenty](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rubyinside.com%2Fwhenever-a-ruby-dsl-for-defining-cron-jobs-1835.html&ei=AhUDUqG6L6OCyAHr0YD4Aw&usg=AFQjCNEFrGrrr5NoZ72KOnDLKfi2lCKIIg&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aWc) of [resources](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F164-cron-in-ruby&ei=AhUDUqG6L6OCyAHr0YD4Aw&usg=AFQjCNE04ApylJphocRHBsvRrsjvq4R2fA&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aWc) to help you decide if it's right for you.